# Toggle multiple elements with same class

Tags: javascript, css, toggle

I've found lots of info on this online but i can't seem to get any of it to work for this.

I am trying to make a button that toggles a light/dark theme on click, changing only the body background colour and the styling of three modal buttons on the page.  My code is working for the button styling, but not for the body background.  I'm quite novice so I think I'm probably just missing something syntactically. argh!

it needs to be in native javascript rather than jQuery.  Any hints would be so appreciated.  Thanks so much in advance!

CSS:

```
.light body {
    background: #D8DDDE;
}

.light .myBtn {

    color:rgb(58, 57, 57);
    background-color: #D8DDDE;
    border-top: solid 4px rgb(58, 57, 57);
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none; 
    transition: 0.6s;

}
```

Javascript

```
var themeSwitch = document.querySelector("footer button");

document.querySelector("footer button").addEventListener("click", toggleText);
   function toggleText() {
      if (themeSwitch.textContent === "Turn the lights off") {
         themeSwitch.textContent = "Turn the lights on";
      } else {
         themeSwitch.textContent = "Turn the lights off";
      }
   }

themeSwitch.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle("light") //this is working for the button but not the body background
})
```

Comment: please show your HTML Code and make runable code..

Comment: Try `body.light` in your CSS (without space) instead of `.light body`

Answer (score 0):

This code is erorr

```
  .light body {
        background: #D8DDDE;
    }
```

plesae changes to

```
body.light{
    background: #D8DDDE;
}
```

```js
var themeSwitch = document.querySelector(".footer button");

themeSwitch.addEventListener("click", toggleText);
   function toggleText() {
      if (themeSwitch.textContent === "Turn the lights off") {
         themeSwitch.textContent = "Turn the lights on";
      } else {
         themeSwitch.textContent = "Turn the lights off";
      }
   }

themeSwitch.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle("light") //this is working for the button but not the body background
})
```

```css
body.light {
    background: #D8DDDE;
}

.light .myBtn {

    color:rgb(58, 57, 57);
    background-color: #D8DDDE;
    border-top: solid 4px rgb(58, 57, 57);
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none; 
    transition: 0.6s;

}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
<button>Turn the lights on</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @imo-vee try this you added stye error use to ```body.light``` class

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `body` from the the css class `.light`.